# coding C# XML byte parser(for class), a way to tell if I'm in a parent or child element

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

For my entry level C# programming class, we're essentially coding our own XML parser (using FileStream and ReadByte() )

We've got a "test.xml" file, that goes...
(my teacher uses container interchangeably with parent element and uses attribute as the child element, he's a bit confusing to those of us that know a bit of xml, but his class is aimed at those that don't know any xml)

```
<containers>

<container>
<attribute1>data for attribute1 of container1</attribute1>
<attribute2>data for attribute2 of container1</attribute2>
<attribute3>data for attribute3 of container1</attribute3>
</container>
///more containers with varying amounts of attributes
...
</containers>
```

Now in his example parser (which we're supposed to study and do our own version of, we can use his structure but he prefers us to switch it up a bit) he uses a constant

```
const string XMLCONTAINER = "container"
```

to check if we're inside a parent element or if we're processing a child element of container

```
if(!gInsideContainer) {

    if(String.Compare(gParseToken,XMLCONTAINER)==0) {
    Console.WriteLine("\n***** BEG OF CONTAINER\n");
    gInsideContainer=true;

    // save the offset of the beginning of the
    // container into the container object
    setAttribute("BEGPTR",gTagOffset.ToString());
 }
```

That seems to me to be bad mojo, as it means I have to edit the source code with every type of xml we end up processing just to figure out if we're in a parent element or not. I'm trying to think, given the code we've got to study off of, how I can do a more generic check to see if I'm inside a parent element or if I'm in a child of a parent element.

I'm thinking about creating an array to hold opening elements, or another string variable to hold the current opening parent element, then checking for its closing element, but that might not work as the ways I'm thinking of implementing it would catch the initial

```
<containers>
```

and set insideContainer to be true for the rest of the parsing (yay logic errors, at least I can spot this one before coding,heh)

I'm not allowed to use any of the .net XML parsing class, (as we're basically rewriting it with less functionality and probably less efficiently, but it's more the experience in problem solving and creating algorithms that he's aiming to teach)

Any suggestions on how I could go about implementing my idea? (and keep in mind, beginning level programmer here,lol)

Thanks much for any help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

A more generic way to push your element into a [stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) each time you parse a new entry tag and pop the top tag from the stack when you exit. If you need to know what your parent tag is you can peek at it.

Better still would be to create a tree structure where each node contains list of child nodes and each child node contains a link to its parent, something like

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public List<Node> Children {get;set;}
    public Node Parent {get; private set}

    public int ElementDepth
    {
        get{ return Parent == null ? 1 : Parent.Depth + 1; }
    }

    public Node(string name, Node parent)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Children = new List<Node>();
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

    public Node(byte[] xml, ref int startAt)
    {
        if(this.Depth == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In Container named \"" + this.Name +"\"");
        }
        /*  in this function:
         *  Get the tag name and either (recursively) create its children
         *  or return if it closes this tag
         */
    }
}
```

then in main all you have to do is load the bytes into memory  and call `Node(myArray, ref myIndexPointer)` and is long as that function is defined properly your done.

Comment: That's a bit confusing, I'm not really that far into OOP. I'm converting a sequential program to a very basic OOP one(for extra credit in converting to OOP). 
basically I have an xmlobject class which stores the elements and data values (parallel arrays atm, but this method has to ignore the original <containers> </containers> tags since they don't have data values and are the root node) and a XMLParse class that does the actual parsing. This class itself doesn't go into OOP at all (officially) as that's covered by a class I have next semester.

Comment: thats one of the pit falls of asking for homework help on SO... i'll try to flesh it out a bit more, but still leaving you some code to write.